# Laravel Timestamp instead of Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

In a simple model, there are as standard `created_at` and a custom field `material_copied_at`
In Blade `$model->created_at` return a Carbon value. `material_copied_at` return an INT

I defined in the model the `$date`

```
class ImportRequestForQuote extends Model
{
const STATUS_NEW = 'new';
const STATUS_MATERIALCOPIED = 'materialCopied';

public $table = 'import_request_for_quotes';

protected $dates = ['material_copied_at'];


public $fillable = [
    'client_id', 'number', 'num_items', 'material_copied_from', 'material_copied_at'
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'client_id' => 'integer',
    'number' => 'string',
    'num_items' => 'integer',
    'material_copied_from' => 'integer',
    'material_copied_at' => 'timestamp'
];

public function items()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ImportRequestForQuoteItem::class);
}

public function materialCopiedFrom()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'material_copied_from');
}
}
```

Why i do not get a Carbon value back when i use `{{ $model->material_created_at}}`

Any help is welcome (I think i miss only a small part...)

Comment: remove `'material_copied_at' => 'timestamp'` from cast array

Comment: @Sohel0415 : Thank you. It works